# Compare dates in PHP

Tags: php, symfony1

I am trying to make a script in PHP that finds if the update time of a record (coming from symfony as a datetime object) is less than an hour away from the time now in other words if the record was updated in the last hour

Here's the code I have so far:

```
$recordDate = $slideshow->getDateTimeObject('updated_at');
$nowDate = new DateTime();
var_dump($showDate < $nowDate);
```

However, this only shows if the updated time is before now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd forgo creating another DateTime object and use DateTime::getTimestamp() and strtotime()

```
if($recordDate->getTimestamp() >= strtotime("-1 hour")) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To know if $recordDate is more recent than one hour ago, instead of comparing it with the current date, you'll need to compare it with the DateTime that corresponds to one our ago.

You'll want something like this :

```
if ($recordDate >= $oneHourAgo) {
    // do something
}
```

If you're using **PHP >= 5.3**, you could use the [**`DateTime::sub`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php) method, to substract one hour to your `$nowDate` DateTime.

For example, first get the current date :

```
$oneHourAgo = new DateTime();
var_dump($oneHourAgo);
```

And, then, substract one hour :

```
$oneHourAgo->sub(DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 hour'));
var_dump($oneHourAgo);
```

And here's the output I get :

```
object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '2011-02-25 21:03:32' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)

object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '2011-02-25 20:03:32' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
```

If working with **PHP 5.2**, you'll need to use [**`DateTime::modify`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php).

Here too, first, create the current date :

```
$oneHourAgo = new DateTime();
var_dump($oneHourAgo);
```

And, then, modify it :

```
$oneHourAgo->modify('-1 hour');
var_dump($oneHourAgo);
```

Of course, this will get you exactly the same kind of output as the first solution ;-)

Comment: I would think you'd want `modify` either way, or else you'd have to create an extra `DateInterval` object first.

Comment: @R I've edited my answer to provide a couple of examples, showing that :-)